# Tooltip in chart with line- and scatter plot in highcharts 3.0.7

Tags: highcharts

In older versions of highcharts you could have a chart with both line and scatter plots and combine them both into the same tooltip like so:

[image]

In highchart 3.0.7 this no longer works. As can be seen in the tooltip below wind dir is not displayed. Win dir is a scatter plot, the others are areaspline:

[image]

The tooltip code:

```
tooltip: {
crosshairs: true,
shared: true,
   formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%H%M %p %a %b %e', this.x) + '</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
             s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y + (this.series.name == 'Wind Dir' ? ' degrees' : ' mph');
        });
        return s;

   }
}
```

See complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/runerei/hphwu/).

How can the tooltip in 3.0.7 be made to behave like in 2.2?

Comment: I opened your example http://jsfiddle.net/hphwu/5/ and in tooltip I see all series, so what is wrong?

Comment: If you comment out ver 2.2 and uncomment ver 3.0.7 you'll see: http://jsfiddle.net/hphwu/6/

Comment: It's changed since ~2.3.5 version and isn't supported anymore, sorry. According do [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround is to change the scatter plot to a line plot and set linewidth = 0 and enable marker for the line plot. This way it will look like the scatter plot in the example, but support tooltip.shared.

Edit: note that the actual property is camelCase: `lineWidth: 0`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was looking for something like the [error bar chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/error-bar), but with a few changes:

- Share the same `yAxis` (both column and error are about the same nature)
- No `errorbar` margin for the columns (but need to keep them for the dots)
- Use of `scatter` instead of `spline` (since the y's aren't connected through time)

So, from the [Highcharts' error bar fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/error-bar/), I came up with the same [*broken* tooltip fiddle for my case](http://jsfiddle.net/y4upb6w3/1/).

---

Digging at the problem, I found that as per [Highcharts' shared tooltips documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared):

> Tooltip texts for series types with ordered data (not pie,
>   scatter, flags etc) will be shown in a single bubble.

So, it really don't make sense to expect a shared tooltip for the `scatter` option.

---

As a solution, I came up with the very same OP's solution.

Set the type as `spline` (even it doesn't make much sense at first) and remove the line by setting `lineWidth: 0` to appear like a `scatter` plot, so it is simulated something like an *ordered scatter plot chart*, as shown in this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/error-bar/).

Comment: Just to explain, I was about to post that as a new answered question, when I found out that existing one. So, I decided to place it here even with all the similarities to help indexing this page on search engines, since I didn't found that answer when trying to find one.